# waking up more than one condition variable

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

Normally, we can signal only one variable like

```
pthread_cond_signal (condition)
```

However,  I want wake up more than one condition variable at the same time. How can I do that?

In other words, Can I give an array to the signal function in order to wake all condition variable stored in that array ?

```
   four condition variable : X, Y, Z, T

   I want :  waking up these four condition over sending signal, at the same time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have made a conceptual mistake in your implementation.

It seems you are trying to share one resource but have assigned many conditional variables to the same resource.

If you are modelling only one resource, every child should NOT have a different condition variable but all should share the same.

So if lets say it's a queue that is protected by conditional variable A all threads that dependent on A should do a `pthread_cond_wait(A)` so that when you do a `pthread_broadcast(A)` every one of those threads gets woken up and the first one there gets to work on the data.

If you really can't change your implementation you could use a stack and pop the first condvar off and insert at bottom. This would guarantee that none will starve as long as there is enough data.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't signal them using an array. You have to call pthread_cond_signal on each variable you want to signal.

Comment: How can I make all call as atomic ?

Comment: You can't. Why do you need them to be atomic?

Comment: I have more than one source and several child thread which will use them. I will wake all thread from their sleep at the same time then make scheduling so that no one will be died from starvation. If I call all condition variable one by one, there will be possibility to starvation.

Comment: Is each thread waiting for a different condition variable to be signaled?

Comment: I dot understand why setting them all ready at once is any different starvation-wise than setting them ready in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not need the conditions for anything else but waking up all children at the same time you could use only **one** condition variable and then issue a  `pthread_cond_broadcast()` to wake up all children waiting on this **one** condtion variable.